# Random loading errors with vue-material components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

I started playing with *Vue.js* and *VueMaterial* this week. It's really fun and totally new for me as I didn't do Javascript for years (Native *Android* being my cup of tea).

I am currently stuck with a very strange issue that I would say related to my lack of knowledge with the framework lifecycle.

### Issue

1. The first time I am loading/refreshing manually the project in Chrome, it fails loading the VueMaterial components for some reason, and I get the message below:

   Unknown custom element: **md-toolbar** - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I get this message with every single VueMaterial components I use in the project (md-whiteframe, md-input-container, and so on).

And the result appears as below:
[image]

2. Now, if I specifically change the URL in chrome by giving the path of another component (e.g. Home), then some components are correctly displayed (except the toolbar for some reason).
3. I go back (with Chrome), and land on the first component, except that now, everything is displayed correctly, still except the toolbar (see below).

[image]

On certain occasion (really **rare** and **completely randomly**, the Toolbar is displayed correctly.

### Context

I installed vue-cli via npm and built the scaffold with the webpack template, then installed VueMaterial with npm as well.

### Code

Below, some bits of the code.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let colorPrimary = {
  color: 'red',
  hue: 700,
  hexa: '#D32F2F'
}

let colorAccent = {
  color: 'yellow',
  hue: 600,
  hexa: '#FDD835'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})

Vue.use(VueMaterial)

Vue.material.registerTheme('default', {
  primary: colorPrimary,
  accent: colorAccent,
  warn: colorPrimary,
  background: 'white'
})

Vue.material.setCurrentTheme('default')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <toolbar></toolbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Toolbar from './components/Toolbar';

export default {
  components: {
      Toolbar
  },
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style src="./styles/general.css"></style>
```

**Toolbar.vue** (custom component)

```
<template>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
      <h2 class="md-title" style="flex: 1">Firebucket</h2>
    </md-toolbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'toolbar'
}
</script>

<style scoped src="../styles/toolbar.css"></style>
```

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="login" class="bg-primary">
    <md-whiteframe md-elevation="2" id="login-form">
      <span class="md-title text-primary">{{wording.login}}</span>
      <md-input-container>
          <label>{{wording.username}}</label>
          <md-input></md-input>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>{{wording.password}}</label>
        <md-input></md-input>
      </md-input-container>

      <router-link id="login-button" tag="md-button" to="XX" class="md-raised md-primary">{{wording.login}}</router-link>
      <br />
      <md-button class="md-primary">{{wording.createAccount}}</md-button>
    </md-whiteframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'login',
  data () {
    return {
      wording: {
        login: 'Login',
        createAccount: 'Create an account',
        username: 'Username',
        password: 'Password'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped src="../styles/login.css"></style>
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Home from './pages/Home'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      alias: '/',
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login
    }
  ]
})
```

--

Again, web development is not my thing, I've heard a lot of good thing about Vue.js so I wanted to give it a try. But sorry if I am missing something really obvious.

I really can't wrap my head around the fact that it's not working the first time but working fine when I go back...

PS: the **router-link** (in Login.vue) doesn't work neither, nothing happens when I tap the button, but I guess that's a different issue.

Any idea anyone? General feedback on the code posted above is more than welcome so I can improve it.

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/remychantenay/FirebucketJS), if that can help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the VueMaterial plugin *after* you create your Vue. Instead, add it before.

```
Vue.use(VueMaterial)

Vue.material.registerTheme('default', {
  primary: colorPrimary,
  accent: colorAccent,
  warn: colorPrimary,
  background: 'white'
})

Vue.material.setCurrentTheme('default')

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: Yep, spot on! I feel like I should have tried that, anyway... Thank you!